# Android: my app is only catching url when not starting with https://

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

I have an android app which is supposed to be launched when an url with my domain is click on.

It's working with all url starting with my domain url but it doesn't if the url is starting with https://

for example:

> "www.example.com/anypage/"

is working but

> "https://www.example.com/anypage"

isn't working

Here is my manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="www.example.com" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Can you share your Manifest XML?

Comment: @PedroOliveira it's done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android filter url in "intent-filter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907373/android-filter-url-in-intent-filter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (https first):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: it still doesn't work :-( i don't understand. Why url are working when starting with www and not when starting with http ???

Comment: Remove www from the URL in the intent receiver